# Crystal Reports - Ocultar encabezado de grupo si el contenido es vacío

Tags: crystal-reports

Estoy intentando ocultar un encabezado de grupo si no muestra datos. Os dejo el esquema:

```
Encabezado de Grupo 1 
Encabezado de Grupo 2
    Detalles (suprimido) 
Pie Grupo 2 (DATOS, QUE A VECES ES VACÍO) 
Pie Grupo 1 (Suma de Datos, que a veces es 0)
```

Consigo ocultar el pie de grupo 1 cuando Suma de Datos es 0 (un total acumulado), pero no consigo ocultar su encabezado, porque claro, cuando se ha evaluado el total acumulado ya se ha pintado el encabezado.
Siempre que DATOS es vacío, la suma me sale 0, por lo que cualquiera de las dos condiciones serviría para ocultar el encabezado.
¿Alguna idea?
Gracias.

Comment: En la opción de visibilidad tienes que ponerle la condicional de @datos not empty. Si a lo que te refieres es que la página entera no tiene records, echale un ojo a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294027/crystal-reports-suppress-a-page-header-if-the-page-has-0-records

Comment: Gracias. El enlace que me has puesto me sirve.
Me ha ocultado buena parte de los encabezados; algunos no porque, aunque no muestro datos por una condición (y el total acumulado sale 0), en verdad hay registros, y quizá por eso no funciona como me gustaría. Pero es un paso.